# Diversity indices by treatment groups and sites in R

Tags: r, plyr, vegan

I am trying to calculate the inverse Simpson's diversity index in R using vegan's `diversity()` function.  I would like to calculate this index for each experimental treatment.

My data looks a bit like this, where `species` is the species x site contingency table and `env` is the treatment factor x site table:

```
spe <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  S1   S2   S3   S4
  0    1    2    1
  0    1    1    0
  1    0    0    3
  0    1    0    1
  1    2    1    0
")  

env <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  Stage
  a
  b
  c
  a
  c
")
```

Ideally, I'd get a single diversity index value for each (a,b,c) treatment factor.

I know that the `specnumber()` function has a groups option, but I don't see anything similar for diversity and was hoping to find an easy way to do the same thing.  I've tried applying `summaryBy()`, `aggregate()`, and `ddply()` without any luck.

I've also tried brute force computing `diversity(subset(spe, env$Stage=="a"),"simpson")` for each individual `env$Stage`but that still gives me a Simpson's diversity index for each site in that stage, not for the stage as a whole.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such `groups` argument in `diversity` because it is not well defined: Do you mean the average diversity of the sampling units in a group, or the diversity of the average of sampling units in a group? They are different things and it is best to explicitly do what you want this index to do.

The first thing is easier: just calculate diversities for SUs and take their average by groups:

```
tapply(diversity(spe, "simpson"), env$Stage, mean)
```

For the diversity of the average community, you first need to aggregate your data by `groups` and then calculate the diversity for each group (and for most indices `mean` and `sum` give the same result in usual diversity() indices, but `sum` works in some cases where `mean` does not):

```
diversity(aggregate(. ~  env$Stage, spe, sum)[,-1], MARGIN=1, index="simpson")
```

`aggregate` wants to add an extra column to name the rows and we must drop it with `[,-1]`, and gives the result transposed and we need to set `MARGIN = 1` (or use `t()` to back-transpose).

As you see, the results are different. Some people call this differences as beta diversity.

Comment: Thanks Jari!  I think this works perfectly.  To clarify, the latter is essentially taking each individual stage and treating it as its own distinct community (i.e., one sample) and calculating its diversity index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your tables are joined row by row (eg. row 1 is "a 0 1 2 1"). If that's the case, maybe this is on the right track:

Make them into a single data frame:

```
spec_env <- data.frame(species, env)

> spec_env
  S1 S2 S3 S4 Stage
1  0  1  2  1     a
2  0  1  1  0     b
3  1  0  0  3     c
4  0  1  0  1     a
5  1  2  1  0     c
```

Use `split` to get a list of data frames:

```
split_spec_env<-split(spec_env, spec_env$Stage)
```

Now, if you need the mean diversity in each treatment, first use `lapply` to get the index for each row:

```
z<-lapply(split_spec_env, function(x){
  x$div<-diversity(x[,1:4], index = "invsimpson")
  return(x)
}
)

> z
$a
  S1 S2 S3 S4 Stage      div
1  0  1  2  1     a 2.666667
4  0  1  0  1     a 2.000000

$b
  S1 S2 S3 S4 Stage div
2  0  1  1  0     b   2

$c
  S1 S2 S3 S4 Stage      div
3  1  0  0  3     c 1.600000
5  1  2  1  0     c 2.666667
```

Then again to get the mean index for each subset (Which I *think* makes more sense but depends what you need):

```
lapply(z, function(x){
  mean(x$div)
})
```

*Or* if you want to take all the values from a subset and get the overall diversity within a treatment:

```
lapply(z, function(x){
  y <- unlist(x[,1:4])
  diversity(y, "invsimpson")
})
```

**Edit:** I realized you may want the diversity index from the summed species within a treatment. If that's the case, use `colSums`:

```
lapply(z, function(x){
  y <- colSums(x[,1:4])
  diversity(y, "invsimpson")
})
```